# Need to run iisreset on site to see changes, even after Visual Studio rebuild?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I haven't seen this before.  I'm working on an ASP.Net Webforms site, and rebuilding it and refreshing the page in question in my browser doesn't reveal any changes.  I have to run iisreset for that to happen.

Is there a setting in Visual Studio 2012 that affects this?  When building, my changes go into the `bin` directory on my site, same as any other changes I've ever made on other sites I've worked on.

This is an older ASP.net site (circa 2005) but it's running in IIS 7 on Windows 7, in a .Net 4.0 app pool and it works fine...except having to run iisreset every time I want to see a change.

Comment: Is it being published to the IIS folder? Try making a change to the web.config file and see if that has an affect.

Comment: Changing web.config did make a difference, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Check your IIS configuration to make sure your application pool recycles on build/configuration changes.

Also check that IIS Output Caching is not turned on for your path.

Comment: I have IIS 10, is *Configuration changes* include build changes?